# Upgrading Windows 7 and keeping files by making a new partition

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1-upgrade

I want to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and keep most of my files but the only option I'm presented is "Keep personal files only".

So I was wondering can I upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and keep my files if I create a new partition and place my wanted files in there? Will my files on that new partition be erased after upgrading?

Comment: I have only one hard-drive and I need to back-up about 10-30GB of data. My upload speed is quite slow so I can't back my data in to the cloud.

Comment: Why don't you just do an in-place upgrade to Windows 8.0 then upgrade that to Windows 8.1 then you don't have to implement your (sort of) crazy plan of creating a new partition.

Comment: Because I currently only have a Windows 8.1 disk available. Creating a new partition is quite easy so I thought if it is possible to create one to transfer files.

Comment: The only partition that will be changed is the system partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work. Just be very careful when working through the install so that you make certain you reformat and install to the first partition not the data partition.